# appendChild() won't work after using replace

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am working on an extension for firefox. I have never made an extension before and my knowledge of JS/JSON/XML is very limited, but luckily there is Google to help.
This code will print every "sName" element in the JSON object:

```
for(var i=0; i<obj.names.length; i++)
{
    var nameItem = createListItem(obj.names[i].sName);
    lb.appendChild(nameItem);
}
```

I am trying to replace any spaces in a name with an underscore.

```
    nameItem = nameItem.replace(/ /g,"_");
```

after the "var nameItem =" line made it stop printing all the names
and

```
    var nameItem = createListItem(obj.names[i].sName).replace(/ /g, "_");
```

had the same negative effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, provided that `sName` is a string:

```
var nameItem = createListItem(obj.names[i].sName.replace(/ /g, "_"));
```

**Update:**

The [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method is only defined for [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype#Methods), not for [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype#Methods) in general.
Calling an undefined method throws an exception.
If the exception is not caught at some point, execution stops.
This is the case here.

I don't know the details of the function `createListItem`, but I imagine it takes a string as an argument and returns an object, likely of supertype [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) since it's being appended to the DOM (note that you can't append strings directly!).
Since Elements don't have a method `replace`, execution stops there where the code tries to call `replace`.

Comment: This worked! Out of curiosity, do you know why it wasn't working before?

Comment: @user2308961 I added some details to my answer, hope that helps.